# classes and constructors throwing wrong type error

Tags: java, class

hello Ive been try for days keep getting the same error.
basically Ive a got this error:
VisaCardDemo.java:24: error:

```
constructor CreditCard in class CreditCard cannot be applied to given types;
    new CreditCard(100.0, 0.03, 2.50, 500.0);
```

required: no arguments
  found: double,double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

basically I've no clue why this is happening its something to do with the constructor not interacting

stemming from this code:

```
public class CreditCard
{
    int numberRepayments = 0;
    int numberDebits = 0;
    double creditCard_Bal;
    double Annual_Interest;
    double monthlyServiceCharges;
    double creditCard_limit;
    //double 


    public CreditCard(double Balance, double interest, double serviceCharge, double limit)
    {
    //I'm unsure if im doing this correctly 

    creditCard_Bal = Balance;
    Annual_Interest = interest;
    monthlyServiceCharges = serviceCharge;
    creditCard_limit = limit;
    //double 
    }
    public void repayment(double repayments){

        creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal - repayments;
        numberRepayments = numberRepayments + 1;

    }
    public int debit(double debit){
        creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal - debit;
        numberDebits = numberDebits + 1;
        return numberDebits;
    }
    public void calcInterest(){
        //Monthly_Interest_Rate = (Annual_Interest / 12);
        //Monthly_Interest = creditCard_Bal * Monthly_Interest;
        creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal * (1 + (Annual_Interest / 12));

    }
    public int monthlyProcess(){
        creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal - monthlyServiceCharges;
        calcInterest();
        numberRepayments = 0;
        numberDebits = 0;
        return numberDebits;
    }
    public double setMonthlyServiceCharges(double placeHolder){
        monthlyServiceCharges = placeHolder;
        return monthlyServiceCharges;

    }
    public double getMonthlyServiceCharges(){
        return monthlyServiceCharges;            // the reason that ive only put the variable 
                                         //is because i think the metho will work as 
    }                                    //in the VisaCardDemo
                                         // fprintf("the monthly service charge = " + cosc120VisaCard.getMonthlyServiceCharges)
                                         //will equal fprintf("the monthly service charge =" monthlyServiceCharges )
                                         // please let me know if this is not the case and i need to do more to it
    public double getBalance(){
        return creditCard_Bal;
    }
    public int getNumRepayments(){
        return numberRepayments;

    }
    public int getNumDebits(){
       return numberDebits;
    }
    public double getInterestRate(){
       return Annual_Interest;
    }    
   }
```

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class VisaCardDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create a Decimalformat object for formatting output.
      DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

      // Create a VisaCard object with a $100 balance, 
      // 3% interest rate, a monthly service charge
      // of $2.50, and a credit limit of $500.
      VisaCard cosc120VisaCard = 
                   new VisaCard(100.0, 0.03, 2.50, 500.0);

                   //
                   //
      CreditCard cosc120CreditCard = 
                   new CreditCard(100.0, 0.03, 2.50, 500.0);
                   //
      //
      // Display what we've got.
      System.out.println("Balance: $" + 
                         dollar.format(cosc120VisaCard.getBalance()));
      System.out.println("Number of repayments: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumRepayments());
      System.out.println("Number of debits: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumDebits());
      System.out.println();

      // Make some repayments.
      cosc120VisaCard.repayment(25.00);
      cosc120VisaCard.repayment(10.00);
      cosc120VisaCard.repayment(35.00);

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.println("Balance: $" + 
                         dollar.format(cosc120VisaCard.getBalance()));
      System.out.println("Number of repayments: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumRepayments());
      System.out.println("Number of debits: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumDebits());
      System.out.println();

      // Make some debits.
      cosc120VisaCard.debit(450.00);
      cosc120VisaCard.debit(50.00);  // credit card account should become inactive
      cosc120VisaCard.debit(10.00);
      cosc120VisaCard.debit(10.00);
      cosc120VisaCard.debit(10.00);

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.println("Balance: $" + 
                         dollar.format(cosc120VisaCard.getBalance()));
      System.out.println("Number of repayments: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumRepayments());
      System.out.println("Number of debits: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumDebits());
      System.out.println();

      // Do the monthly processing.
      cosc120VisaCard.monthlyProcess();

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.println("Balance: $" + 
                         dollar.format(cosc120VisaCard.getBalance()));
      System.out.println("Number of repayments: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumRepayments());
      System.out.println("Number of debits: " + 
                         cosc120VisaCard.getNumDebits());
   }
}
```

```
public class VisaCard extends CreditCard
{                            
   // double visaCard_Bal;
   // double visaCard_Interest;
    //double visaCard_ServiceCharge;
    //double visaCard_Limit;
    boolean tf = false;
    double temporary_storage;

    public VisaCard (double V_Balance, double V_interest, double V_serviceCharge, double V_limit)
    { 
        creditCard_Bal = V_Balance;       //dose this make the VisaCard class the super?

               //end constructor
        }

                public int debit(double debit)             
                {
                if (creditCard_Bal >= creditCard_Bal) 
                    tf = false;
                else{
                    creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal - debit;
                    numberDebits = numberDebits + 1;
                    return numberDebits;
                    }
                }

                public double repayments(double money)//calls  the superclass version
                {
                super.repayment(money);

                if (creditCard_limit >= creditCard_Bal) 
                     tf = true;
                }



                public int monthlyProcess()
                {
                if (numberDebits > 10)
                    temporary_storage = monthlyServiceCharges;
                    monthlyServiceCharges = monthlyServiceCharges + (10 - numberDebits);
                    if (creditCard_Bal > creditCard_limit)
                        tf = false;
                    creditCard_Bal = creditCard_Bal + monthlyServiceCharges;
                    super.monthlyProcess();
                    monthlyServiceCharges = temporary_storage;


            }                                       

}
```

Comment: I think the question has done something wrong this is meant to be java

Comment: Recompile your `CreditCard` class. It's looking for a no-arg constructor, so I'd wager that you've got an old `.class` file lying about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why call super() in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp not a duplicate. The error comes from `VisaCardDemo.java:24` for the reason I stated.

Comment: @Kayaman I respectfully disagree. I copied and pasted into ideone and changed the ctor to be `super(V_Balance, V_interest, V_serviceCharge, V_limit);` and it compiled and ran (after fixing a few missing `return` statments). https://ideone.com/VQIF96

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's why I said there's an old class file that needs to be recompiled. You don't need to agree, the exception states exactly what is wrong according to the OP's compiler. A constructor with 4 `double` params is called, but the compiler finds only a no-arg constructor in `CreditCard`: `required: no arguments found: double,double,double,double`.

Comment: @Kayaman Compiling OP's code with the original ctor produces the _exact_ error message given. The compiler is trying to call the default ctor, but it is not provided - and one is not automatically provided because of the user-created one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ah, sorry then. It's misleading when the line numbers don't match the messages (and Ideone's style of error messages).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the error is perfectly correct and it is telling what compiler is looking for. It is looking for no arg constructor and found parameterized constructor. 
So here are few basics-

1. Java creates default constructor in a class only if it doesn't see any constructor. Here you created your own parameterized cons. so java didn't supply her own default cons.
2. Either you write or don't write, the first call from child class constructor is call to parent class constructor. If you write explicit then you can call either the super() or super (args). If you don't call super cons. on first line of child class cons. then java will automatically put super() call to parent class default cons.

Here in your case, you don't have default cons. in creditcard class and have defined parameterized cons. hence java didn't supply it's default cons.
Now in child class cons. visacard, you didn't call any cons. on very first line

```
    public VisaCard (double V_Balance, double V_interest, double V_serviceCharge, double V_limit)
        { 
        //There is a hidden super(); call here
        creditCard_Bal = V_Balance;       //dose this make the VisaCard class the super?
         //end constructor
            }
```

So even though you didn't put any super call, but java supplied super() by default. Now your parent class is missing something like below

```
public CreditCard(){
   //default cons
}
```

So it is bound to fail and failing. It will keep failing until you define either the no-argument cons. in parent class or call the parameterized cons. explicitely in your child class cons. very first line.
You would also like to visit below links-

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054040
2. [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12798462/6532664

As a best practice, it is good to have default cons. if you are creating parameterized cons. in your class (Until you are sure that someone will never inherit it). You never know who becomes child of your class and doesn't call parameterized cons. of your parent class hence it will fail this error. Java will look for cons. with no arguments but will find something with argument.

Hope it helps.